# Who can illuminate me about getting max per line?

Tags: c#, arrays, row, max

This is my code:

I am trying to get the maximum per line, everything is going ok until the last row. It shows me 8, but should be 4.

```
        int[,] vek = new int[,] { { 2, 5 }, { 4, 5 }, { 8, 5 }, { 4, 2 } };
        int sumL=0;
        double media = 0;
        int maxL = 0;
        maxL = vek [0,0];

        Console.WriteLine("\tL1\tL2\tTotal\tMedia");
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int row = 0; row < vek.GetLength(0); row++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}.\t", row + 1);

            for (int col = 0; col < vek.GetLength(1); col++) {
                Console.Write(vek[row, col] + "\t");
                sumL += vek[row, col];// SUMA
                media = (double)sumL / vek.GetLength(1); //Media

                if (maxL < vek[row,col])
                {
                    maxL = vek[row, col];
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(sumL + "\t" + media + "\t" + maxL);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `maxL` back to 0 (or, better yet, `int.MinValue`) at the start of each row. Simply moving its declaration into the outer for loop would be a good way to do this.

Your code gets 5, 5, 8, 8 for the maximum because, without reseting `maxL`, it's taking the maximum of the rows so far instead of the maximum of each row independently.

Comment: @VictorB if you feel that this answered your question well, do please accept it with the check mark.